# Farming bot to recompound on quickswap using web3.py: StakeWithPermit v, r and s missing

Tags: web3.py, polygon, staking

I'm using web3.py for farming and recompoundig on quickswap. I want to claim rewards, swap to the original tokens, add liquidity and verify the transaktion.

I use the abi of the farm contract to access the contract functions. For example for adding liquidity:

```
tx = contract.functions.addLiquidityETH(token=token, amountTokenDesired=amountTokenDesired, amountTokenMin=amountTokenMin, amountETHMin=amountETHMin, to=to, deadline=deadline).buildTransaction({'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(myAddress), 'value': value})
```

The last step is to use the function:

```
stakeWithPermit(uint256 amount, uint256 deadline, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s)
```

Here I need the parameters v, r and s. How do I get them?
Theoretically, I could get them from a signed transaction but I need them already for building the transaction.

```
tx = contract.functions.stakeWithPermit(amount=amount, deadline=deadline, v=v, r=r, s=s).buildTransaction({'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(myAddress)})
txSigned = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, pkey)
txHash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(txSigned.rawTransaction)
w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(txHash, timeout=600)
return w3.toHex(txHash)
```